Scrapy python estou com duvidas
Olá, eu estou com dificuldade para realizar um script de mapeamento sobre um site. Eu preciso localizar uma classe que está dentro de uma div, na qual é: "class="Blob Blob_Green".
Essa classe está dentro da tag <tbody> e quando eu faço o Scrapy, ela me retorna "None"
Pode ser que eu esteja fazendo errado, mas eu preciso de uma ajuda nesse quesito


class mapTilerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mapTilers"
    start_urls = [
        "https://status.maptiler.com/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for mapTilers in response.css("tbody"):
            yield {
                "Divs": mapTilers.css("div::attr(class)").getall()
                }

            print(mapTilers) 


Não duplique perguntas, siga as orientações já fornecidas na pergunta original. Se precisar comentar, faça na pergunta original, também.
